# PowerShell get File ID

Tags: powershell, file

Is it possible to use PowerShell to get the ID of a file?
I mean the ID you get, if you use `fsutil.exe`.

```
fsutil file queryFileID C:\temp
```

Comment: Sure. Run `fsutil file queryFileID "C:\path\to\file"`.

Comment: ;-) I mean not fsutil, i mean an other method without the exe, a "powershell native".
There are so much functions in PS, maybe someone knows it.

Comment: I don't think this information is available via .Net APIs or even WMI. From what I was able to dig up you'd need the Win32 API for getting access to this (quite obscure) bit of information.

Comment: Short answer: No. Long answer: You might be able to do it but would have to compile a lot of custom code to call Win APIs in PowerShell. Using fsutil would be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Workaround via Get-SMBOpenFile

I know this is older, but I don't see a good answer, so I'm going to throw one out. @marzse short answer was correct, there isn't a PowerShell native command that will give you the same output as `fsutil`. You can get an int64 FileID from `Get-SMBOpenFile` if the file is open anywhere. Then you can convert that to hexadecimal with some .NET magic.

```
# gives us a 32 bit hex FileID for Comparison
fsutil file queryFileID C:\temp

# Get an int64 FileID
$int = Get-SMBOpenFile | Where-Object Path -eq "C:\temp" | Select-Object -Property FileID -Expand Property
 
# Convert int64 to hex32 and append 0x
$temp = '{0:x32}' -f $int
$hex = '0x' + [string]$temp

# Compare the two
if($hex -eq "pasted Hex from fsutil") {Write-Output "True"}
```

It's not an easy answer, but it took longer to write this post than it took me to figure it out, so I wouldn't call it complicated either. If you have to do it a lot, put it into a function or script and call it a day.